# React Routing V6 problem, redirecting to another path: '/contact' the content from <Contact /> get updated above nav instead of separate page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to make Airbnb Clone using React 18, but above nav something like this is happening:

I am using React BrowserRouter V6, whenever we redirect to another page like **localhost:3000/about**, the about page should open instead of the whole page rendering on all the paths:

[image: </About Us> component]

[image: component]

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Title from './Components/Title.js'
import Tagline from './Components/Tagline.js'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar.js'
import Firstpara from './Components/Firstpara.js'
import Card from './Components/Card.js'
import React, { Components } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">  
  
      <div className="header">
        <Title />
        <Tagline />
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <Firstpara />
      <Card />

      {/* <Contact/> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "../Pages/About"
import Contact from "../Pages/Contact"
import Features from "../Pages/Features"
import Error from '../Pages/Error'

export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="navbar container-fluid">
                <Router>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
                        <Route path="/features" element={<Features />} />
                        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
                    </Routes>

                    <div id="right-menu">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#worldclass">Visit</a></li>
                            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/features">Features</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your app.js file change your code to this (this is just for a demo) you change it as your requirements**

```
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route,} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
return (
 <>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login"  element={<Login />}/>
      <Route path="/register" element={<Login />}/>
    <Routes/>
  </BrowserRouter>
 </>
 );
```

Comment: Thanks, @amir-sahzad worked for me after I asked it, I put all the files in the components folder, and took the Router in another file.  See source code: [github repo](https://github.com/NisooJadhav/airbnb),

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you have is that the `Navbar` is rendering *all* the routing code, the router, routes, *and* the links. Then additionally it is rendering the routes *above* the links.

Move the `Router` and routes out to the `App`. The `Router` should wrap the `Navbar` and routes, and the routes should be rendered below the `Navbar`/header.

Example:

App

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">  
  
        <div className="header">
          <Title />
          <Tagline />
          <Navbar />
        </div>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/features" element={<Features />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Routes>

        <Firstpara />
        <Card />

        {/* <Contact/> */}
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Navbar

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar container-fluid">
      <div id="right-menu">
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#worldclass">Visit</a></li>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/features">Features</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got the point I did the same as your answer. [github repo](https://github.com/NisooJadhav/airbnb). Thanks for the answer.